# talking computer

Tags: windows-7, text-to-speech

Last week, a person at work had this really cool program on his computer. When you inserted a usb flash drive, the computer said like "flash drive inserted". Does anyone know what this program is called or know about any similar program?

btw: it was on windows 7

I don't want to talk to the computer, I just want the computer to talk to me at different actions

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like its just a Windows Sound theme to me....

Answer (score 1):

[Talking Desktop](http://www.talkingdesktop.com/)

> Senses when the room is quiet and calls out for some attention by saying John, where are you ?

:)

Comment: And when you open the disk tray, it tells you "I'm sorry Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."?

Comment: @Gnoupi: "No John, I've headache today!" ;P